# Iterate through objects using their tag (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a lot of buttons, labels, fields, on a form for which would like to set a number of properties (e.g., textAlignment, font, isEditable, backgroundColor, etc.).  Because there are so many, I don't want to create outlets or have hundreds of lines of code (e.g.,

```
f1.textAlignment = .center
f2.textAlignment = .center
...
f1.isEditable = false
f2.isEditable = false
...
```

Since I can easily assign each a unique tag, how would I do this by iterating thought their tags instead?

Something along the lines of:

```
for tag in 0 ..< 75 {
   object[tag].textAlignment = .center
   object[tag].isEditable = false
}
```

(Or is there a better way?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like working with tags, but you can do something like this:

```
for tag in 0 ..< 75 {
    let taggedView = view.viewWithTag(tag)
    switch taggedView {
    case let label as UILabel:
        label.textAlignment = .center
    case let button as UIButton:
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    default:
        print("could not cast view")
    }
}
```

Just cast the view to each specific type, like `UILabel` or `UIButton`.

Comment: Why don't you like working with tags?  Is there a better way?

Comment: Because all views have `0` as their tag, by default, iirc and you might forget which tags are which

Answer (score 1):

I would collect the controls into different arrays so that I have a button array, a text field array and so on and then loop over the arrays to set the properties

```
let buttonArray: [UIButton] = [button1, button2,...]
let textFieldArray: [UITextField] = [field1, field2,...

for field in textFieldArray {
    field.textAlignment = .center
    field.font = ...
}
```

Comment: But I would need to create outlets for each and every one of those controls, wouldn't I?

Comment: @Greg Outlets or variables both works fine. A button created in code is still a UIButton

Comment: @Greg if you made each control in the storyboard, you **will** need to connect them with outlets first. Then you can group the outlets into an array as shown above, so that you can configure them easier.

Comment: Actually, it was the labels I was thinking about - I have no outlets for them.  Yes, everything else does have an outlet.  I could use tags on the labels and outlets for everything else.

Comment: Remember you can always connect an element to a collection (array), so you can say `@IBOutlet var labels:[UILabel]!` and simply connect all of your labels to the one outlet via a collection outlet

Comment: @Paulw11 I wish IBOutlet collections were available in macOS.