# How to iterate through subviews in Swift for macOS and return object types

Tags: swift, nsview, nsstoryboard

After finding [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64705137/iterate-through-objects-using-their-tag-swift?rq=1), I thought I would try to reduce the size of my code considerably by looping through various objects in the view and set parameters.

I cannot use the tag value because I do not set tags, except in rare circumstances.  I set plain language identifiers for all of my UI elements.  I will use NSTextField as an example to try and set the delegate for each NSTextField in the view.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var myTextField1: NSTextField!
    // ... and many, many more NSTextFields ...

    override func viewDidLoad {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let textFields = self.view.subviews.filter { $0.isKind(of: NSTextField.self) } 
        for textField in textFields {
            if textField.identifier!.rawValue[textField.identifier!.rawValue.startIndex] != "_" { // Avoiding Swift assigned identifiers
                textField.delegate = self
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am being told that `Value of type 'NSView' has no member 'delegate'`, which makes sense because the NSView of the NSTextField is what is actually being placed into the list, not the actual NSTextField object.

Since IBOutlet Collections aren't available for macOS, I can't simply iterate through a collection to do what I want to do.  At least as a far as I know of.

Comment: This is not a UIKit issue.  I am not developing for iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the goal is to get `textFields` to have type [NSTextField].

Right now, you have `filter` with `is` (which doesn't change type)

`let textFields = self.view.subviews.filter { $0.isKind(of: NSTextField.self) }`

You should change this to `compactMap` with `as?` (which does change type).

`let textFields = self.view.subviews.compactMap { $0 as? NSTextField }`